# Informatica update strategy and unconnected lookup not working as expected

Tags: informatica

I am trying to working on a table with two columns and developing an update strategy with an unconnected lookup. I am using the two columns PAYER_NM and ST_CD as keys. I had marked PAYER_NM as L port and ST_CD column as O/L/R port. The logic for lookup is on both the columns. When I try to make a change to one of the existing record with the same PAYER_NM but changing only the ST_CD column value. I want the only the ST_CD value of the record in the target table be updated for the same PAYER_NM column value. But the result for is that it keeps inserting a record into the target table instead of update. I would like to know how and what changes I need to make in my code to get what I need as above.

I tried using only one key column PAYER_NM and making other column ST_CD as non key column and vise versa.

Comment: You need to share info for us to help you i.e. what is the exact expression in your update strategy so we can see where you've set DD_UPDATE and where you've set DD_INSERT. Is the session configured to treat putput rows as insert, update or data driven? Also the field names are hard to relate, might make it easier to understand if you explain what they mean

Answer (score 0):

Plese check session property - if its set to 'Insert' only. If not check the target properties and see if its insert only as well.
You can use UPDATE Starategy too to ensure update is working fine.